# mdframed and a title with a footnote

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

I have put the title of my text in `mdframed`, however the title has a footnote.  After I LaTeX the file, the footnote appears inside the frame rather than in its usual place, i.e. at the bottom of the page.  I wonder how this problem can be fixed.

Comment: Is the problem in the fact that the framed text splits across pages, leaving the footnote mark on one page and the footnote text on the following?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a separate `\footnotemark`-`\footnotetext` combination should work, as in the following minimal working example. The former *inside* and the latter *outside* the `mdframed` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/mdframed
\usepackage[paperheight=15\baselineskip]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  Some text\footnote{A footnote}.
\end{mdframed}
\bigskip
\begin{mdframed}
  Some text\footnotemark.
\end{mdframed}
\footnotetext{Another footnote.}
\end{document}
```

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was used just for this example.

---

For page-breaking related placement of footnotes, the following is a possibility, however hackish. Using the above approach, `\footnotetext` will only place the footnote at the end of the `mdframed`, possibly on an incorrect page. Manual adjustment of the footnote counter could help:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{lipsum,mdframed}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{lipsum,mdframed}
\usepackage[paperheight=15\baselineskip]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\begin{document}
\begin{mdframed}
  Some text\footnote{A footnote}.
\end{mdframed}
\bigskip
\stepcounter{footnote}
\footnotetext{Another footnote.}
\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}
\begin{mdframed}
  Some text\footnotemark. \par
  \lipsum[1]
\end{mdframed}
\end{document}
```

Using `\footnotetext[\the\numexpr\value{footnote}+1\relax]{Another footnote.}` could also work, assuming an `\arabic` setting for a footnote.

Comment: It was helpful for me too, but I wonder if there is an alternative for the second issue. It would be a bit tedious to write these lines every time again, so, do you know of any alternative methods? (Of course I could replace those 3 lines `\stepcounter{footnote}\footnotetext{Another footnote.}\addtocounter{footnote}{-1}` by a single command. Possibly I'll do that if no alternative shows up.) Thanks in advance.