# Footnotes in mdframed: Why are they not at the bottom of the page?

Tags: footnotes, mdframed

When I use the `mdframed` environment around a table, I encounter two problems: (1) The footnotes do not appear at the bottom of the page; (2) The footnotes are marked with letters, while the rest of the footnotes in my document are in Arabic.

I tried using the `tablefootnote` package, but did not have much success. I wrote `\footnotemark{}` where I want a footnote, and then put `footnotetext[1]{Text I want}` outside of the mdframed environment. But this seemed like a really bad idea, because I need to manually adjust the footnote numbering if I add footnotes earlier in the document. (For example: if I add a footnote earlier than this one, I would need to go back and change `footnotetext[1]{Text I want}` to `footnotetext[2]{Text I want}`.)

I have included a screenshot:

[image]

And the code that produced the screenshot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %allows footnotes in tables to appear outside the table
%%table packages
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
If I have footnote in the text\footnote{The first footnote} it gets put at the bottom of the page. But if my footnote is inside the \fbox{mdframed} environment, then the footnotes don't appear.

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{table}[H]
\hspace{-5mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{35mm}  p{25mm} <\raggedright }
\underline{Column 1} & \underline{Column 2} \\
Text & more text \\
Text with footnote\footnote{I want this footnote to be at the bottom, and in Arabic numbering!} & ?? \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{mdframed}

This should be footnote number three\footnote{The third footnote}, but it is footnote number two.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Environment `mdframed` is based on `minipage` hence the position of footnotes within `minipage` is inherited.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113640/print-mdframed-footnotes-at-bottom-of-page-instead-of-after-frame, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/602771/how-to-make-footnote-for-framed-theorem-appear-at-bottom-of-page, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88447/mdframed-and-a-title-with-a-footnote

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %allows footnotes in tables to appear outside the table
%%table packages
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\begin{document}
If I have footnote in the text\footnote{The first footnote} it gets put at the bottom of the page. But if my footnote is inside the \fbox{mdframed} environment, then the footnotes don't appear.

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{table}[H]
\hspace{-5mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{35mm}  p{25mm} <\raggedright }
\underline{Column 1} & \underline{Column 2} \\
Text & more text \\
Text with footnote\footnotemark{} & ?? \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{mdframed}\footnotetext{I want this footnote to be at the bottom, and in Arabic numbering!}

This should be footnote number three\footnote{The third footnote}, but it is footnote number two.

\end{document}
```

> Edit: Some kind of hack to the original marcos. Two new marcos `\myfootnotemark`,`\myfootnotetext` have been defined to function similar to the original one. However it will update the footnote counter when the `\myfootnotetext` used. In order to make the superscript footnote number in main content to correctly typed, some temp counters have been defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{tablefootnote} %allows footnotes in tables to appear outside the table
%%table packages
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\newcounter{myfn}
\newcounter{tpmyfn}
\makeatletter
\def\myfootnotemark{%
   \@ifnextchar[\@xfootnotemark
     {\stepcounter{myfn}%
      \setcounter{tpmyfn}{\value{footnote}+\value{myfn}}%
      \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thetpmyfn}%
      \@footnotemark}}
      
\def\myfootnotetext{%
     \@ifnextchar [\@xfootnotenext
       {\stepcounter{footnote}\setcounter{myfn}{0}\protected@xdef\@thefnmark{\thempfn}%
    \@footnotetext}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
If I have footnote in the text\footnote{The first footnote} it gets put at the bottom of the page. But if my footnote is inside the \fbox{mdframed} environment, then the footnotes don't appear.

\begin{mdframed}
\begin{table}[H]
\hspace{-5mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{35mm}  p{25mm} <\raggedright }
\underline{Column 1} & \underline{Column 2} \\
Text & more text \\
Text with footnote\myfootnotemark & some text \\
Text with footnote\myfootnotemark & some text \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{mdframed}\myfootnotetext{one}\myfootnotetext{two}

This should be footnote number three\footnote{The third footnote}, but it is footnote number two.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work if I want more than one footnote in my table. I just tried this code with two footnotes, and it made them both footnote 3 (i.e. I now have two footnotes at the bottom of my page that are both numbered 3). I suppose one could write \footnotetext[2]{second footnote} and \footnote[3]{third footnote}, but then I have to manually update these numbers if I include any footnotes earlier in the document...

Comment: @Sam I update my answer to include a solution.

Comment: Thanks for all this effort!

Comment: @Sam You are welcome

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I think I figured out a way to do it. It is based on an answer by @Bernard in this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/520067/footnote-outside-theorem-environment). It works for `framed`, but strange things happen if I try to merely include the code `\usepackage{mdframed}`! If I include this in the preamble (without changing anything else), I get an error when the compiler comes to the first footnote in the table. Strange!

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{framed}{\savenotes}
\AfterEndEnvironment{framed}{\spewnotes}



\begin{document}
If I have a footnote in the text\footnote{The first footnote} it gets put at the bottom of the page. But if my footnote is inside the \fbox{framed} environment, then the footnotes don't appear.

\begin{framed}
\begin{table}[H]
\hspace{-5mm}
\begin{tabular}{p{35mm}  p{25mm} <\raggedright }
\underline{Column 1} & \underline{Column 2} \\
Text & more text \\
Text with footnote two\footnote{footnote 2} & ?? \\
Text with footnote three\footnote{footnote 3} & more text\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{framed}

Now to test with footnotes outside of the `framed` environment: footnote number four\footnote{footnote 4}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Such a nice suggestion, using `mdframed.sty`